# Compressed Network Streams Design

Tags: c#, stream, compression

I am looking for some fast / low latency stream implementations for C#/.Net, and would be interested what is out there. These streams will be reporting live market data, so I am interested in low latency, as well as moderately high compression, and the data will be pushed out on a TCP stream.
What options are available to compress a TCP stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize your data with [Protobuf.net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which reduces the size by being densely encoded.

As Marc says, it's probably better to use a raw socket.

Comment: Technically, it is just densely encoded - not "compressed" as such. But I second your recommendation ;p Except I would probably use a raw socket in the scenario presented.

Comment: (by which I mean: protobuf-net on a socket, rather than protobuf-net over WCF ;p)

Comment: Dense encoding is important, lets assume I've already compacted my binary representations. What would you do to compress your data even more?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: lol sorry, I had this opened in two windows. Submitted the partially updated one :)

Comment: @Superman google's protocol buffers is pretty much that; so if you're confident in your internal representation it may not be for you. For most people, it is a practical way to *achieve* a dense stream without lots of pain.